# AskUbuntu vs UnixLinux Stack: Where to post?

Tags: discussion, support, ubuntu

Ubuntu seems to be so relevant, that it has **a dedicated Stack exchange page.**

But how do I know, **when to post** at Ask<s>MintSuSEcentOSGentooArchWindowsReactOS</s>Ubuntu and **when to post at Unix/Linux.StackExchange.com?**

The latter one is probably for more general questions. But I guess, that AskUB.SE would also fit for similar distributions such as LinuxMint or Ubuntu-Studio (which I use at the moment, burned DVD).

Comment: Note that Linux Mint is absolutely not on topic on [ubuntu.se]. Only *official* Ubuntu flavors are on topic there. Please see the [the relevant help page](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic).